# Adding apache-airflow library to PyCharm

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualenv, virtualbox, airflow

*I've been trying to wrap my head about how can I add apache-airflow library to my virtual env in windows.*

1. Apache-airflow is installed on **Linux** which is hosted by
   **VirtualBox** on my machine.
2. PyCharm is installed on Windows 10 where I am trying to figure a way
   how to add that **library** to my PyCharm(Community Edition).

Basically I want to keep apache-airflow on my virtual machine and develop DAGs and necessary components on my Windows environment.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run the code on the windows machine? Or just develop on the windows machine?

Comment: Just develop on windows machine I guess

Comment: So PyCharm on Windows would just act like an interface if that is possible

Answer (score 2):

If the code is going to be running on the linux VM. Add the python library on the VM. Create a shared folder between your Windows machine and the VM. Save your pycharm project in the shared folder.

This will "work" but have a few significant draw backs:

1. Pycharm won't have any "code completion" for the imported libraries.
2. Pycharm will complain that the library doesn't exist.
3. You will have to test your code either through ssh to the remote machine or in a terminal on the remote machine.

Another option is to just install pycharm in the linux VM, if you are using a linux distro with a desktop, like ubuntu for instance.

If pycharm isn't required, VS Code has a nice plugin for remote development:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh